# Jasmine - Instantiate angular factory that accepts arguments

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, factory

I have a factory i'm trying to test in Jasmine. It looks like this:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory("TestObject", function() {
      function TestObject(name,description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
      }
        return TestObject;
});
```

I want to test it with Jasmine, so i'm trying:

```
describe('Factory: TestObject', function() {
  beforeEach(function () {
        module('myApp');

        inject(function ($injector) {
            testObject = $injector.get('TestObject');
        });
  });
});
```

My question is: How can I use $injector.get when I need to send parameter into the factories constructor?

Thanks! Uri

Comment: Your code is very confusing. Is the service named TestObject or TestObjectModel? Is the module named myApp or appModelEditor? $injector.get will return the service. The service is a function taking a name and a description as arguments. You're free to call the function returned by $injector.get() with any name and description you want.

Comment: Sorry, you're absolutely right, I fixed the mistakes. I though get already instantiates the function, i'll try your suggestion